# remove all except letters and single spaces in a column

Tags: php, mysql

column `title` is like this:

```
14 blue5 sky
3 5gold sun"
'/lorem   ip25sum
  light moon
```

I need to remove everything except letters and single spaces between words.

So the above example should be:

```
blue sky
gold sun
lorem ipsum
light moon
```

Any help?

**phpMyAdmin:**

```
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: @Nick, can't see mysql version, but phpMyAdmin is `4.8.3`  if matters

Comment: On your PhpMyAdmin home page it should have the MySQL server version.

Comment: Seems dangerous to just strip everything but letters.  It's better to figure out how this happened and correct that issue.

Comment: @Nick, maybe this - `mysqlnd 5.0.12`

Comment: On the phpMyAdmin home page there is a section titled "Database server". In there will be a line like: `Server version: 5.6.35-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)` what is in that?

Comment: @Andreas not `php` but phpMyAdmin is 4.8. `php` is 7.2

Comment: @Nick, see my update, pls

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yes, seems dangerous, but I will create a table backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a nested `REGEXP_REPLACE` to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '[^[:alpha:] ]', ''),
           '^\\s+', ''),
         '\\s+', ' ') AS newtitle FROM table1
```

The first `REGEXP_REPLACE` removes any non-alphabetic characters; the second removes any spaces at the beginning of the string, and the final one replaces any sequences of one or more spaces with a single space.

Output (for your sample data):

```
newtitle
blue sky
gold sun
lorem ipsum
light moon
čć đš hello
```

To update the values in the table, you can use this query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET title =  REGEXP_REPLACE(
               REGEXP_REPLACE(
                 REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '[^[:alpha:] ]', ''),
                 '^ ', ''),
                '\\s+', ' ')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=678b86c77c510a63f2e36b8defb515d2)

Comment: @puerto I've updated the answer and demo for multibyte characters